# Optimizing Postgres query

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-performance

I've got a one to one relation from users to addresses table.
Where one user can have one search address and one verified address.

I've got two indexes on addresses table :

- Index on state field
- Index on user_id

I'm trying to fetch addresses for certain users only, and those addresses whose state is other than `manual_verification`.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT users.id 
FROM "users" INNER JOIN addresses 
     ON  addresses.user_id = users.id 
     and addresses.type = 'VerifiedAddress' 
WHERE ("users".deleted_at IS NULL) 
  AND (users.id in (11144,10569,21519,783,15671,21726,17787,11665,
                    19579,12226,1324,9413,5461,20981,12906) 
  and addresses.state != 'manual_verification')
```

Explain for the query above :
http://explain.depesz.com/s/rTj

It takes 37 ms. Sometimes more depending on the number of users.

I think this is a good query, however our team needs to investigate around this, and I'm looking for some optimization tips. I mean I did the one field select, there is a index on user_id (addresses) and state (addresses).

Is there anything else I can do/try?

**Update**

I found out that this query works much faster:

```
 SELECT "addresses"."user_id" 
    FROM "addresses" 
    WHERE "addresses"."type" IN ('VerifiedAddress') 
    AND (user_id in (9681,23824,23760,20098,962,14730,12294,9552,534,
                     553,5837,6768,6583,956,24179) and state != 'manual_verification')
```

Explain for this query:
http://explain.depesz.com/s/nHrr

Comment: Please provide the plan for the query. Preferably here - http://explain.depesz.com/

Comment: Of course, it uses only 1 of the 2 tables. If there is a foreign key on `user_id` that references the `users(id)`, which should be, then you are fine. But the second query does not take into account the `(users.deleted_at IS NULL)` condition.

Comment: Do you have an index on `(deleted_at)` ?

Comment: @ypercube no I don't have index at delete_at, should I have it?

Comment: Its ok that it doesn't take into account delete at because the address is dependent relation, it will get deleted if the user is deleted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm trying to fetch addresses for certain users only ...

`IN` does not scale well with big lists. Compare performance to [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) / `JOIN`

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   unnest(ARRAY[9681,23824,23760,20098,962,14730,12294,9552,534,
                    553,5837,6768,6583,956,24179]) AS t(user_id)
JOIN   addresses a USING (user_id)
WHERE  a.type  =  'VerifiedAddress'
AND    a.state <> 'manual_verification'
```

I hope `state` and `type` are at least [`enum`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-enum.html) types. Otherwise you should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database design. Have lookup-tables for `state` and `type` and only use a small IDs referencing entries there. Makes the `addresses` table smaller and everything faster.

Assuming all columns `NOT NULL` for lack of information.

#### [Partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html)

If you need it faster still, and if there are more than a few rows with `type <> 'VerifiedAddress'` or `state = 'manual_verification'`, a partial index would help some more. The gain grows with the percentage of rows you can exclude from the index.

```
CREATE INDEX addresses_selection_idx ON addresses (user_id)
WHERE  type  =  'VerifiedAddress'
AND    state <> 'manual_verification';
```

Be sure to use matching `WHERE` conditions in your query to allow Postgres to use this index. And weigh the benefit of tailored indexes against their cost (maintenance, extra disk space, small penalty for write operations).

Comment: hi Erwin, what do you consider to be a big list for in not to scale well?

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow: Actual numbers depend on the details of your installation and query. In a quick test on Postgres 9.1 with integer categories on a big table (1MM rows) with index , `IN` was about twice as fast with a hand full of items. `unnest()` took the lead starting at ~ 160 items. Run a few tests with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to find the characteristics in your installation.